# How do I change the name of a scheme in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, target

A picture seems better than a confusing title:

[image]

I have copied my main app to different targets. 
I also managed to change the `productnam`e under Build Settings of the targets. 
I see that my `(Productname)` change effects the `Bundle ID`, so I guess this is ok.

Now how can I change the name of the scheme?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

- Click on **Manage Schemes...**
- Click on the name you want to edit (under the **Scheme** column).
- Enter the new name, then press the return key.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I guess I am an MAC Dummy :-). Will accept soon. Accept is blocked for 7 minutes.

Comment: Ha, it is good. I used to duplicate it with a different name and delete the old one

Comment: this answer is now invalid, there's no "scheme" column

Comment: @airtonix this answer is definitely still valid. This is the only way to change the name.